# How to format data stacked highchart?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am trying to implement stacked chart like below format

getting data like this

```
var pastData  = [
  {
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "amount": 580
  },
  {
    "xlabel": "01-07/11",
    "amount": 100
  }
]

var futureData = [
{
    "xlabel": "01-07/11",
    "amount": 120
  },
  {
    "xlabel": "08-14/11",
    "amount": 620
  },
  {
    "xlabel": "15-21/11",
    "amount": 100
  }
]
```

trying to format dala like below for stacked chart

```
[["25-31/10", 580], ["01-07/11", 100], ["01-07/11", 0], ["08-14/11", 0], ["15-21/11", 0]], "pastformatdata"
[["25-31/10", 0], ["01-07/11", 0], ["01-07/11", 120], ["08-14/11", 620], ["15-21/11", 100]], "  this.futuredates"
```

[image]

ABOVE

-->  **red** color bar represent past week data

-->**cyan** color bar represent future week data

-->**red+cyan** color bar represent **current** week data

so I formated data like this

```js
var pastData  = [
  {
    "xlabel": "25-31/10",
    "amount": 580
  },
  {
    "xlabel": "01-07/11",
    "amount": 100
  }
]

var futureData = [
{
    "xlabel": "01-07/11",
    "amount": 120
  },
  {
    "xlabel": "08-14/11",
    "amount": 620
  },
  {
    "xlabel": "15-21/11",
    "amount": 100
  }
]

var pastformatdata = [];
var futureformatdata = [];

 var weeklyviewcatogies = [...pastData, ...futureData];
    console.log(weeklyviewcatogies, 'this.weeklyviewcatogies');
    for(var i = 0; i < pastData.length; i++) {
      var temp = [];
      temp.push(pastData[i].xlabel);
      temp.push(pastData[i].amount);
      pastformatdata.push(temp)
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < futureData.length; i++) {
      var temp = [];
      temp.push(futureData[i].xlabel);
      temp.push(0);
      pastformatdata.push(temp)
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < pastData.length; i++) {
      var temp = [];
      temp.push(pastData[i].xlabel);
      temp.push(0);
     futureformatdata.push(temp)
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < futureData.length; i++) {
      var temp = [];
      temp.push(futureData[i].xlabel);
      temp.push(futureData[i].amount);
      futureformatdata.push(temp)
    }
    console.log(pastformatdata, 'pastformatdata')
    console.log(futureformatdata, '  this.futuredates')
```

Here how to get sum of duplicated of innerarray get uniq . need to remove duplicates get sum of arr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdACm.png)

Is this correct way to format data?? any suggestion to implement to implement chart like above  image

Comment: Let's start from this template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n1dcy6mk/ is this an output which you wanted to achieve? What more should be done with this chart?

Comment: how to add and remove chart dynamically in angular

Comment: Have you already seen the Highcharts Angular wrapper documentation? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular I think that you can find an answer to it. In case of any trouble please reproduce your attempt on some online editor and ask a specific question.

Comment: I create another question,, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648112/how-to-dynamiccally-add-and-remove-highchart-in-angular-10