# How to dynamiccally add and remove highchart in angular 10?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I need to show NO data image when chart is removed,,

I am unable to add/ remove the highchart

I tried like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-demo-h1cm75?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Highcharts module called `no-data-to-display` because using `innerHTML / outerHTML` is not ideal because it's not pertuculary safe.
I recreated it in Angular similarly to what you might see in the API (I used a slightly simpler example since your has additional thins and seeing the difference might be difficult).

First I imported the module and initialized it with the Highcharts. Then I used the recommended way of updating the data. 
When the data array is empty, Highcharts handles that and show a message that there is no data. You might customize that mesage- see the API.

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/noData 
**Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-no-data-to-display

Comment: Its working How to customize that along with message I need to show one image aswell

Comment: In the lang object, add property `noData` where you specify your custom text message. Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-no-data-to-display-yttkxe

Comment: custom text fine how to add image ?

Comment: Where this image should be placed? Instead of the text? Please give me some reference.